# Health Manager in Cloud Foundary?

Tags: cloud-foundry, paas

I am trying to understand the architecture of cloud foundry

1. For every application deployed on the cloud is there one Health Manager for each application ? Or Is there only one health manager that monitors all the application deployed on the cloud ? Can you give me an example ?
2. What is a NFS Server used for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is only one Health Manager for all running apps. Multiple HMs can be deployed for high availability reasons, but HM nodes do not map to application instances. See http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/high-availability.html for more info on scaling CF components.
2. NFS server is used as a blobstore for application droplets.